# No value accessor for form control with name - Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

this is the exact error being faced :

> QuizComponent.html:11 ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control
>   with name: 's'

I'm trying to create a quiz app with 4 options(buttons) using JSON.The user-provided answer is compared with JSON provided answer on click of `Next` button.I've seen other search results here regarding this error which asks to use Forms, but since I'm not creating anything having explicit input but simple value of button,I guess Forms shouldn't be used.

PS: This code was working perfectly before I implemented clickable buttons in HTML for quiz options. I was using radio buttons earlier.Something is wrong with ngModel two way binding and really not sure what is it as the HTML code is displayed correctly if I remove ngModel tag from buttons or otherwise the buttons are not shown if I write ngModel inside them.

HTML:

```
 <div *ngFor="let actiVar of activeArray ;let j = index">

        {{actiVar.QuestionID}}.{{actiVar.Question}}
        <br>
        <br>

        <button type="button" name="s" id="oneans" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="actiVar.OP[j+0]" [disabled]="permission">{{actiVar.OP[j+0]}}</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" name="s" id="oneans" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="actiVar.OP[j+1]" [disabled]="permission">{{actiVar.OP[j+1]}}</button>        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" name="s" id="oneans" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="actiVar.OP[j+2]" [disabled]="permission">{{actiVar.OP[j+2]}}</button>        <br>
        <br>
        <button type="button" name="s" id="oneans" [(ngModel)]="hello" [value]="actiVar.OP[j+3]" [disabled]="permission">{{actiVar.OP[j+3]}}</button>
        <br>
      </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-light" id="button1" *ngIf="this.fLoop != this.questArray.length" (click)="filterAnswer(hello)">Next</button>
```

.TS:

```
filterAnswer(i: any) //Comparing Answer submitted by user with JSON provided answer
  {
    this.correctAns = this.activeArray[0].isRight;
    this.lastIndex = this.activeArray[0].QuestionID;
    if (this.correctAns == i && this.correctAns != this.storeArray[this.storeCounter - 1]) {
       console.log(i);

      this.storeArray[this.storeCounter] = i; //Only the correct answer provided by user gets stored here.
      this.storeCounter++;

      this.scoreCounter++;
}
    }
```

Comment: why are you using `[(NgModel)]` directive on button tag?

Comment: What should be the ideal approach? As far as I know, using ngModel on buttons worked for me earlier.

Comment: And why do you have several elements with the same name/id, which is anti-pattern for html coding.

Comment: same name - so that only one answer could be selected at a single point & same id - for css.

Comment: Two-way Binding in Angular is the synchronization between the model and the view. When data in the model changes, the view reflects the change, and when data in the view changes, the model is updated as well and for button tag you should use `events` not `[(ngModel)]` directive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use ngModel on buttons. Use simple (click) event and store data in variable. Do something like this:

```
<button type="button" name="s" id="oneans" [disabled]="permission" (click)="getUsersAnswer(actiCar,OP[j+0])">{{actiVar.OP[j+0]}}</button>
```

and in your .ts file just store that value in some variable:

```
getUsersAnswer(answer: any) {
   this.i = answer;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad i could help! :)